# Open source Tool for modeling a Firebird database

Tags: open-source, database, modeling

I am looking for a open source tool for modeling my Firebird database. Don't know if there are any specific ones for Firebird or a universal one.

I know IBExpert for Firebird modeling but it's not open source.

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by "modeling"? Exactly what kind of features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could FlameRobin work for you? It has a few features of being,

- lightweight (small footprint, fast execution)
- cross-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris)
- dependent only on other Open Source software
- and it works with Firebird databases

## [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org/)

[image: FlameRobin UI]